# How to put a newline for every n'th sentence?

Tags: python, string, newline

Struggling with how to add a new line for every 5th sentence in a long text string.

Input example

```
text = 'The puppy is cute. Summer is great. Happy Friday. Sentence4. Sentence5. Sentence6. Sentence7.
```

Desired output:

```
The puppy is cute. Summer is great. Happy friday. Sentence4. Sentence5.
Sentence6. Sentence7.
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: How are sentences defined?  Do you allow input such as Mr. or other abbreviations?  Or ellipses?  etc  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: The sentences start with a capital letter and end with a full stop. so the full stops could be used to differenciate sentences

Comment: Your example contains lower case for the first letters.  Does that mean you want it to not use capitals to differentiate?

Comment: Happy for capitals to be used. I'll update my example above with capitals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expression.  Add \n after 5 matches of "[not .] followed by .".

```
import re
text = 'The puppy is cute. Summer is great. Happy friday. sentence4. sentence5. sentence6. sentence7.'

print(re.sub(r'((?:[^.]+\.\s*){5})',r'\1\n',text))
```

A more advanced regex sentence matcher that handles abbreviations and other punctuation, by matching on ending punctuation.
Reference: https://mikedombrowski.com/2017/04/regex-sentence-splitter/
Note: there are still edge cases that this fails on, such as T.V. followed by Mr. needs double spaces to denote a separate sentence. Quotations with sentences in them will be split up.  etc.

```
import re
sentence_regex = r'((.*?([\.\?!][\'\"\u2018\u2019\u201c\u201d\)\]]*\s*(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z][a-z]\.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<![A-Z]\.)\s+)){5})'
text = 'The puppy is cute. Watch T.V.  Mr. Summers is great. Say "my name."  My name is.  Or not... Happy friday? Sentence4. Sentence5. Sentence6. Sentence7.'
text += " " + text

print(re.sub(sentence_regex,r'\1\n',text))
```

Anything more complex than this you may want to look into a language processing toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
text = 'The puppy is cute. Summer is great. Happy friday. sentence4. sentence5. sentence6. sentence7.'
splittext = text.split(".")
for x in range(5, len(splittext), 5):
    splittext[x] = "\n"+splittext[x].lstrip()
text = ".".join(splittext)
print(text)
```

Comment: Thank you for the function!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function that adds a newline to the end of 5th sentence

```
def new_line(sentence: str):
    # characters that mark the end of a sentence
    end_of_sentence_markers = ['.', '!', '?', '...']
    # after n sentences insert new_line
    n = 5

    # keeps track 
    count = 0
    # final string as list for efficiency
    final_str = []
    # split at space
    sentence_split = sentence.split(' ')

    # traverse the sentence split
    for word in sentence_split:
        # if end of sentence is present then increase count
        if word[-1] in end_of_sentence_markers:
            count += 1
        # if count is equal to n then add newline otherwise add space
        if count == n:
            final_str.append(word + '\n')
            count = 0
        else:
            final_str.append(word + ' ')


    # return the string version of the list
    return ''.join(final_str)
```

Here is a modified version:

```
def new_line_better(sentence: str, n: int):
    # final string as list for efficiency
    final_str = []
    # split at period and remove extra spaces
    sentence_split = list( map( lambda x : x.strip(),  sentence.split('.') ) )
    # pop off last space
    sentence_split.pop()
    
    # keeps track 
    count = 0
    # traverse the sentences
    for sentence in sentence_split:
        count += 1
        if count == n:
            count = 0
            final_str.append(sentence+'.\n')
        else:
            final_str.append(sentence+'. ')

    # return the string version of the list
    return ''.join(final_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
text = 'The puppy is cute. Summer is great. Happy friday. sentence4. sentence5. sentence6. sentence7.'

out = ''
for i, e in enumerate(text.split(".")):
    if (i > 0)  & (i % 5 == 0):
        out = out + '\n'
    out = out + e + '.'
out
```

result:

```
'The puppy is cute. Summer is great. Happy friday. sentence4. sentence5.\n sentence6. sentence7..'
```

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehension

```
text = 'The puppy is cute. Summer is great. Happy friday. sentence4. sentence5. sentence6. sentence7.'
lines = text.split(".")
result = ".".join([l if i % 5 else "\n"+l for (i, l) in enumerate(lines)]).lstrip()
print(result)
```